# Notifications using RemoteViews is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to add RemoteViews to Notifications and have written the following code:

```
public  void remoteViewNotification(View v)
{
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName() , R.layout.notification_view);

    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_image, R.drawable.android_nougat_h1);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_text, "Text for the Custom Ttext");
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nougat)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());

}
```

The layout for the same is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notif_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notif_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notif_image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However on issuing the notification by pressing the button and calling method remoteViewNotification there is an error

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification : Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification
```

What exactly is the reason for the same. Kindly update where am i making a mistake.

Comment: do you have these icons `R.drawable.android_nougat_h1` & `R.drawable.nougat`?

Comment: otherwiseit dosent compile

Comment: you're right, but i just used my icon and it's working on my phone. maybe your icons are large. my android version is 4.1.2

Comment: I am testing it on api 25 emulator. the same icon is working for simple notification.

Comment: test it on real device

Comment: but why not working on the emulator. Changed the image and it is still not working.

Comment: emulators are unable to work like real devices in some cases.

Comment: on android 24 and above use setCustomContentView instead of setContent , it is working